# Should I make crappy items for crafting writs?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

I completed my first writ last night(woodworking) and got a bunch of loot related to my writ. When I filled the writ I figured I'd make the cheapest stuff I could to see what the reward is. My questions is would I get better loot if I turned in higher level items?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No, the items' quality creating for the quest of the crafting writ don't matter.**

You did enough by creating the simplest items. Their quality doesn't matter, so the style and their feat.

Comment: Awesome, that's what I wanted to hear!